# How to get client Screen Resolution Width/Height at Server Side

Tags: asp.net

I can get client screen resolution using client side script 'javascript',

but I dont want to do that.

I also tried `Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth`, but it always return fixed width as `680`.

Any Idea?

Comment: Why don't you want to use javascript?

Comment: A service/server does not by default define the notion of a local "Screen". What are you trying to do?

Comment: Oded I already told I can do that from JS but I dnt want, I am asking for other ways....

Comment: One use-case for this is SSR.  Currently you need to render all the html and use css to "display: none" the elements you don't need.  This doesn't work very well with vue, because it unnecessarily keeps track of all virtual node state.  If the server had access to a client's resolution from the start then you could appropriately use vue's "v-if" to skip over elements that don't need to be rendered on the client.

Answer (score 14):

Information such as client screen resolution is **never** sent to the server in the HTTP request so you may forget about it. The only way is to use javascript and then pass this information to the server (AJAX, form post, link, ...). You could also use some proprietary browser plugin like Flash, Silverlight, Java Applet, ActiveX, ...

Answer (score 4):

I've just had to do something similar, and what I've done is use Javascript to set a cookie when the user loads the login page, then every subsequent request can retrieve the cookie server side.

The approach is not without it's limitations, but it does provide the information you need for the most part.