# Change Gridview columns visibility when running on mobile ?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, mobile

Giving the Gridview  :

```
  <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODS">   
   <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product" 
      DataField="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName">
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Unit Price" 
      DataField="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice"
        DataFormatString="{0:c}">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Units In Stock" 
      DataField="UnitsInStock" 
      SortExpression="UnitsInStock"
        DataFormatString="{0:d}">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Quantity Per Unit" 
      DataField="QuantityPerUnit"></asp:BoundField>
  </Columns>            
  </asp:GridView>

  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS"
        runat="server"
        SelectMethod="GetItems">     
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

How can I hide columns , i.e. set them on `Visible=false` when the device 
that's running is mobile ?

Usually I use

```
 @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
...
}
```

but it only suits for the CSS classes .

What I'm trying to do is to set the first column on `Visible="false"` using

```
Grid.Columns[0].Visible = "false" ;
```

From the code behind , when the device's resolution is below `max-width:480px` .

Is it possible to use the `@media screen and` for that purpose ?

I've tried to use `<%= %>` but it doesn't work with the `max-width:480px` .

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        {
            Grid.Columns[0].Visible = "false";
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

I have even tested on Chrome simulate a mobile device using the `Toggle device mode` using the developer tools

Also you can use this two properties to get the size:

```
Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth
```

and

```
Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to use Visible and not css class, you have to send width information from client side, using cookie or hidden field
See this post: [How to get client Screen Resolution Width/Height at Server Side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507697/how-to-get-client-screen-resolution-width-height-at-server-side)

What is wrong with CssClass? you want asp.net to not render the column at all?

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product"  CssClass="HideInMobile"
  DataField="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName">
</asp:BoundField>
```

In css:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:480px) {

   .HideInMobile{
    display:none;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If using bootstrap.css you can use:

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-md visible-lg" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-md visible-lg">
```